# mozRTCSessionDescription undefined

Tags: twilio, twilio-video

After getting an email from Twilio with the title "Twilio Video JS SDK and Firefox 68 Breaking Change" which suggest that applications with twilio-video package version 1.18.0 and below will have breaking changes for the new firefox 68, I went to update my npm package to version 1.18.1 but now when I try to open my app in firefox quantum 67.0.4 I get the following error:

```
ReferenceError: mozRTCSessionDescription is not defined

./node_modules/@twilio/webrtc/lib/rtcsessiondescription/firefox.js
node_modules/@twilio/webrtc/lib/rtcsessiondescription/firefox.js:4

  1 | /* globals mozRTCSessionDescription, RTCSessionDescription */
  2 | 'use strict';
  3 | 
> 4 | module.exports = typeof RTCSessionDescription !== 'undefined' ? RTCSessionDescription : mozRTCSessionDescription;
```

Bug?,
Is there a fix to this?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the reasons this can happen is that you or an addon has disabled WebRTC.
If you paste this into the JS console

```
console.log(window.RTCSessionDescription, window.mozRTCSessionDescription);
```

and it shows `undefined undefined` that is very likely the cause of the error you get. Check the value of `media.peerconnection.enabled` in Firefox about:config page and enable it if it is disabled.

Comment: Yes sir, you were absolutely right. That was the problem. I only have one question though, how did you come to this conclusion?

Comment: after more than half a decade of working with this stuff on a daily basis... you know these things. https://github.com/twilio/twilio-webrtc.js/pull/107 should make things work a bit better in this situation.